# Graphviz: Prevent edges from crossing cluster

Tags: graphviz, dot

I'm trying to create two columns of nodes with a number of edges between them. I have this so far, but the edges cross through the B-cluster. So I think I need to have more space between the clusters, without adding more space between the contained nodes. How do I approach this?

I can increase the `nodesep` to get more space between the clusters, but this has no effect on the edges being routed through the B-cluster. In fact, they go even further out to the right of B than with the original `nodesep`.

[Image (large-ish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3xgv.png)

```
graph {
    direction=TB;

    center=true;
    ranksep=0.0;
    nodesep=0.1; 
    fontname=Baskerville;
    fontsize=12;

    node [ fontsize=10; fixedsize=true; width=2.5; height=0.2; shape=plaintext; style=filled; ];

    subgraph clusterA {
        a1 -- a2 -- a3 -- a4 -- a5 -- a6 -- a7 -- a8 -- a9 -- a10 -- a11 -- a12 -- a13 -- a14 -- a15 -- a16 -- a17 -- a18 -- a19 -- a20 -- a21 -- a22 -- a23 -- a24 -- a25 -- a26 -- a27 -- a28 -- a29 -- a30 -- a31 -- a32 -- a33 -- a34 -- a35 -- a36 -- a37 -- a38 -- a39 -- a40 -- a41 -- a42 -- a43 -- a44 -- a45 -- a46 -- a47 -- a48 -- a49 -- a50 -- a51 -- a52 -- a53 -- a54 -- a55 -- a56 -- a57 -- a58 -- a59 -- a60 -- a61 -- a62 -- a63 -- a64 -- a65 -- a66 -- a67 -- a68 -- a69 -- a70 [ style=invis; ];
    }

    subgraph clusterB {
        b1 -- b2 -- b3 -- b4 -- b5 -- b6 -- b7 -- b8 -- b9 -- b10 -- b11 -- b12 -- b13 -- b14 -- b15 -- b16 -- b17 -- b18 -- b19 -- b20 -- b21 -- b22 -- b23 -- b24 -- b25 -- b26 -- b27 -- b28 -- b29 -- b30 -- b31 -- b32 -- b33 -- b34 -- b35 -- b36 -- b37 -- b38 -- b39 -- b40 -- b41 -- b42 -- b43 -- b44 -- b45 -- b46 -- b47 -- b48 -- b49 -- b50 -- b51 -- b52 -- b53 -- b54 -- b55 -- b56 -- b57 -- b58 -- b59 -- b60 -- b61 -- b62 -- b63 -- b64 -- b65 -- b66 -- b67 -- b68 -- b69 -- b70 [ style=invis ];
    }

    {
        a1 -- b23 [ constraint=false ];
        a2 -- b37 [ constraint=false ];
        a3 -- b46 [ constraint=false ];
        a4 -- b42 [ constraint=false ];
        a9 -- b68 [ constraint=false ];
        a10 -- b47 [ constraint=false ];
        /* more edges to be added */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. If I use `splines=ortho`, the edges stay between the two clusters. They don't look as nice, but that's ok.

```
graph {
    direction=TB;

    center=true;
    ranksep=0.0;
    nodesep=0.3; 
    fontname=Baskerville;
    fontsize=12;
    splines=ortho;

    node [ fontsize=10; fixedsize=true; width=2.5; height=0.2; shape=plaintext; style=filled; ];

    subgraph clusterA {
        color=white; /* hiding the cluster box so it doesn't interfere with the edges */
        a1 -- a2 -- a3 -- a4 -- a5 -- a6 -- a7 -- a8 -- a9 -- a10 -- a11 -- a12 -- a13 -- a14 -- a15 -- a16 -- a17 -- a18 -- a19 -- a20 -- a21 -- a22 -- a23 -- a24 -- a25 -- a26 -- a27 -- a28 -- a29 -- a30 -- a31 -- a32 -- a33 -- a34 -- a35 -- a36 -- a37 -- a38 -- a39 -- a40 -- a41 -- a42 -- a43 -- a44 -- a45 -- a46 -- a47 -- a48 -- a49 -- a50 -- a51 -- a52 -- a53 -- a54 -- a55 -- a56 -- a57 -- a58 -- a59 -- a60 -- a61 -- a62 -- a63 -- a64 -- a65 -- a66 -- a67 -- a68 -- a69 -- a70 [ style=invis; ];
    }

    subgraph clusterB {
        color=white;
        b1 -- b2 -- b3 -- b4 -- b5 -- b6 -- b7 -- b8 -- b9 -- b10 -- b11 -- b12 -- b13 -- b14 -- b15 -- b16 -- b17 -- b18 -- b19 -- b20 -- b21 -- b22 -- b23 -- b24 -- b25 -- b26 -- b27 -- b28 -- b29 -- b30 -- b31 -- b32 -- b33 -- b34 -- b35 -- b36 -- b37 -- b38 -- b39 -- b40 -- b41 -- b42 -- b43 -- b44 -- b45 -- b46 -- b47 -- b48 -- b49 -- b50 -- b51 -- b52 -- b53 -- b54 -- b55 -- b56 -- b57 -- b58 -- b59 -- b60 -- b61 -- b62 -- b63 -- b64 -- b65 -- b66 -- b67 -- b68 -- b69 -- b70 [ style=invis ];
    }

    {
        a1 -- b23 [ constraint=false ];
        a2 -- b37 [ constraint=false ];
        a3 -- b46 [ constraint=false ];
        a4 -- b42 [ constraint=false ];
        a9 -- b68 [ constraint=false ];
        a10 -- b47 [ constraint=false ];
        /* more edges to be added */
    }
}
```